# Automatic button scaling based on window size C#/XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, transform, scale, resolution

i'm fairly new at this so i apologize in advance if i say anything stupid.

I am making a UI in WPF that consists of 8 buttons to open various programs set on my computer. Currently i am trying to get the buttons in the UI to scale based on the detected window size.

The problem i am having is trying to get the calculations done in the C# code to link over to the scale transform option for the buttons in XAML.

I have searched high and low to find a solution but i still cannot find a way to link the value to XAML. Does anyone know of a guide for something like this and should it be done using a converter?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Scale to the *screen resolution*? Not the window size?

Comment: Chuck them into a [ViewBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and save your sanity.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Yup window size is what im trying to scale to. Screen resolution was a bad term to use on my part XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you need your content to autoscale, put it all into a [`ViewBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control.

```
<Window>
   <Viewbox>
      <Grid x:Name = rootGrid>
      </Grid>
   </Viewbox>
</Window>
```

Now everything will magically fill to the window size *and* scale! Instant awesomeness for your app.

Comment: (and Chris W.) Thanks so much guys it works great! I had played around with it a bit before but wasnt quiet sure if it was what i needed but im playing with it now and its working! Im assuming if i want stuff to downscale i need to set the max view box height and width to 1920x1080 pixels and when a smaller screen (pixel wise) is used it will auto scale everything down right?